# Is it possible to use CamcorderProfile without audio source?

Tags: android, video, record

My code:

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);

mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);

CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(QUALITY_LOW);
mediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);
```

It works.
But I need to record only video.

And if I don't use mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(), mediaRecorder.setProfile() fails with IllegalStateException.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MediaRecord.setProfile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setProfile%28android.media.CamcorderProfile%29):

> **public void setProfile(CamcorderProfile profile)**
>
> Since: API Level 8 Uses the settings
>   from a CamcorderProfile object for
>   recording. This method should be
>   called **after the video AND audio
>   sources are set**, and before
>   setOutputFile().

From [Android - CamcorderProfile docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html)

> Each profile specifies the following
>   set of parameters:
>
> - The file output format
> - Video codec format
> - Video bit rate in bits per second
> - Video frame rate in frames per second
> - Video frame width and height,
> - Audio codec format Audio bit rate in bits per second
> - Audio sample rate
> - Number of audio channels for recording.

I'd say you could read the relevant video-related settings from a desired CamcorderProfile and set them explicitly yourself.

Comment: This should indeed be applicable to any tailoring of the CamcorderProfiles; e.g. if you do not want to use the default video bit rate but a different one (not all the profile parameters can be changed, and some are rounded to the nearest possible value)

Answer (score 5):

The method setProfile() of MediaRecorder

[image: Implementation]

we can see,if:

```
profile.quality >= CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_LOW //1002
&&
profile.quality <= CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_QVGA //1007
```

there will not setAudio*() 
So in your code you can manually set `profile.quality=[any int from 1002 to 1007]` before `setProfile()`.
It will work, I'v tried.

I'v found the right answer:

```
if (getIsMuteShooting()) { // with out audio                                     
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);                  
    mRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate);                
    mRecorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);              
    mRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);                
    mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec);
} else {
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);              
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);               
    mRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate);                
    mRecorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);              
    mRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);                
    mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(profile.audioBitRate);                
    mRecorder.setAudioChannels(profile.audioChannels);              
    mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(profile.audioSampleRate);                
    mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec);              
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(profile.audioCodec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(profile.fileFormat);
mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec);
```

Comment: Please add some description  in answer which make it helpful for OP and others